# Angular 6 Firebase returning duplicate data

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angular6, angularfire2

I have this Angular 6 application where I'm using Firebase to store data but I think there is an issue with the way I'm saving/retrieving my data because sometimes the data is duplicated.

So when I create a new recommendation using `submitRecommendation()` the data is created once but when I go to view it or retrieve it using `showMyRecommendations()` or `showAllRecommendations()` I see some data being duplicated. I figured it's an issue with the `snapshotChanges()` callback so I tried changing it for `valueChanges()` but that didn't help.

I also tried creating `myRecommendationList` and `allRecommendationList` AngularFireList objects but that didn't solve my issue. Am I retrieving data with the correct way? Everything in my code seems to work fine beside the duplication of data.

```js
recommendationList: AngularFireList < any > ;
allRecommendations = [];
myRecommendations = [];

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.recommendationList = this.firebase.list('recommendations');
}


showAllRecommendations() {
  this.recommendationList = this.firebase.list('recommendations', ref => {
    return ref.orderByChild('name').equalTo(this.data.name);
  });
  this.recommendationList.snapshotChanges().subscribe(list => {
    this.allRecommendations = [];
    list.map(item => {
      this.allRecommendations.push(item.payload.val());
    });
    console.log(4444, this.allRecommendations);
  });
}

showMyRecommendations() {
  this.uid.subscribe(uid => {
    this.recommendationList = this.firebase.list('recommendations', ref => {
      return ref.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(uid);
    });
  });
  this.recommendationList.snapshotChanges().subscribe(list => {
    this.myRecommendations = [];
    list.map(item => {
      this.myRecommendations.push({
        $key: item.key,
        ...item.payload.val()
      });
    });
    console.log(5555, this.myRecommendations);
  });
}

submitRecommendations() {
  const idea = this.ideaForm.value['idea'];
  this.uid.subscribe(uid => {
    if (idea) {
      this.recommendationList.push({
        uid: uid,
        idea: idea,
        like: 0,
        dislike: 0,
        name: this.data.name
      });
      this.ideaForm.reset();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: please empty the recommendationList  before each data fetching, may be the data that is push during submit is present during the fetch data object too.

Comment: @NibinBaby Thank you for taking the time to get back to me. I have tried **recommendationList = null;** but that didn't fix my problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @sbattou did you clear it in the methods, this.recommendationList = null;

Comment: Looks like there is an issue opened before but got closed and the weird behavior still exists. Currently I will just do a client side de-dupe. Follow the issue here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1728